# Testing Loading state in async operation in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following React component, that on `componentDidMount()` performs an async operation and once data is received, updates the state with the result.

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface IAppProp {
    App: any
}

export interface IAppProp {
    App: any
}

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProp, IAppState> {
    constructor(props: IAppProp) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { App: undefined };
    }
    public componentDidMount(){
        // Some async operation
        // Once data comes in update state as follows 
        this.setState({ App: data returned from async operation });
    }
    public render() {
        if (this.state && this.state.App) {
            return (
                <SomeComponent />
            )
        } else {
            return <span>Loading...</span>
        }
    }
}
```

However, while I wait for data to come back, I return a `Loading...` message in the `render()` function.

I'm trying to test this Loading state in my Jest test. This is what I have so far:

```
 it("Should display loading when state is undefined", () => {
    const inputControl = enzyme.mount(<MyApp App={pass in the right prop} />);

    expect(inputControl.find("span").text()).toEqual("Loading...");
});
```

I know the above is wrong because it never finds the Loading `span`. I also tried passing `undefined` in the props but that crashes the test because the async operation in `componentDidMount()` expects a legit prop.

How can I test this? Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to test this by [mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks) the async operation in your test or/and add `async` to your test. Could you provide the full code for `componentDidMount`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example based on your code (modified since I don't have `SomeComponent`, the async function wasn't specified, etc.).

Given this component defined in `App.tsx`:

```
import * as React from "react";

const getMessageById = (id: number): Promise<string> => {
  return Promise.resolve('Message ' + id);
}

interface IAppProp {
    messageid: number
}

interface IAppState {
    message: string
};

export class App extends React.Component<IAppProp, IAppState> {
    constructor(props: IAppProp) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { message: '' };
    }
    public componentDidMount(){
        // Some async operation
        // Once data comes in update state as follows 
        getMessageById(this.props.messageid).then((message) => {
          this.setState({ message });
        });
    }
    public render() {
        if (this.state && this.state.message && this.state.message.length > 0) {
            return (
                <div>The message: {this.state.message}</div>
            )
        } else {
            return <span>Loading...</span>
        }
    }
}
```

A test `App.test.tsx` can be created as follows:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';

import { App } from './App';

describe('App', () => {

  it ('Should display loading until data arrives', async () => {
    const inputControl = mount(<App messageid={1} />);
    expect(inputControl.html()).toBe('<span>Loading...</span>');
    // Let the event loop cycle so the callback queued by 'then' 
    // in 'componentDidMount()' has a chance to execute
    await Promise.resolve();
    expect(inputControl.html()).toBe('<div>The message: Message 1</div>');
  });

});
```

For your actual component you will likely need to mock the async function that is getting the data (so you avoid making network requests, etc.), but this should provide a solid start for what you are trying to do and is the best I can do with the information provided.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroing (just a little)

I find that it's hard to test *everything* from business logic to rendering all in 1 go.

So I split the tests to:

- Testing side effects, i.e. prop/state changes, from user interactions and/or async operations
- Testing snapshots of exact prop/state combinations that I expect to receive.